# how to use all cpu with nodejs

Tags: node.js, socket.io

We have a production chat app built in socketio/nodejs.
We use express.
Nodejs is a bit old : 10.21.0
SocketIO in 3.1.1

Our computer is a VM with 4vCPU and 16 GB RAM.
We use pm2 to manage starting node app with env variables.

We are facing an issue when there are about 500 users in chat and when they write. Bandwidth usage is around 250 Mbps in upload (but we have 10G so no issue). Issue begins here, we can see in our logs full of connection/disconnection and pm2 restart app.
In checking in more details, in launching "pm2 monit" we can see that only one processor is used and it is higher than 100% most of the time.

We read few documentation about clustering (cluster + fork). It seems to be interesting but in our case when we tested it, it's like we had few chat apps so for the same "chat room", users are in different workers so it's not OK.

Do you have an idea how we can fix that and use all processor/core ?
We are already thinking of starting with upgrading nodejs?
Thanks

Niko

Comment: i have faced same issue in my recent app
we then started cluster mode but socket not worked because socket only know clients connected to its process then later on we have implemented to redis to syncing sockets

Answer (score 1):

Since Node.js is always single-threaded (aside from [worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#worker_threads_worker_threads)), upgrading Node won't get you much anywhere (aside from newer Nodes shipping newer V8 engines, which might be faster).

> it's like we had few chat apps so for the same "chat room", users are in different workers so it's not OK.

This sounds like you've architected your app to use global variables or in-process state like that for these shared rooms. If you want to use cluster or PM2's multiple process mode, that state will need to live somewhere else, maybe a second Node application or, say, a Redis server.

Comment: ok thanks both of you for informations, we will try with redis